# How to create a .war file in JDeveloper 11g?

Tags: ide, jdeveloper, jdeveloper-11g

How can I create a .war file of an application in JDeveloper 11g?

Answer (score 2):

Please refer to ["Oracle Fusion Middleware Java EE Developer's Guide for Oracle Application Development Framework 11g Release 1 (11.1.1.4.0) - 8 Deploying an ADF Java EE Application"](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17904_01/web.1111/e16272/deploy_java_ee_app.htm#ADFJE446). This should have all the information you need to create WAR deployment profiles for your application.

Answer (score 1):

you can create a war file for an UI application. Click on the application, select project properties and navigate to the deployments tab. Select the type of deployment as WAR and add the dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

simplest way is just right click on the UI project and hit deployment. it will deploy with a default profile which is good unless you have some specific requirements